# iPad retina stretches non-retina images in Cocos2d

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display, ipad-3

I have a iPad app built with SDK 5.1 (Xcode 4.4). The app is a non-retina app. On iPad 1 and 2 the images are scaled properly. On the new iPad (3rd generation) all the images get scaled up. This behaviour is kind of expected, but undesired in my situation. How do I prevent the images from being scaled up?

Comment: Do you have retina versions for all images properly included in your Xcode project?

Comment: No, not at all. So if I add the same images again (same sizes) but just with @2x added to them, it should work?

Comment: No, the Retina images should double the dimension. If Non-Retina is 100x100 then Retina should be 200x200.

Comment: Keep in mind if you are developing a cocos2d app as your tags indicate that cocos2d uses -hd as it's default suffix for retina images whereas most iOS API calls use @2x as has been indicated already.  Reference cocos2d docs at http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d?s[]=retina on developing for retina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are building for both Non-Retina and Retina devices you should include both versions of all images. The Retina images should be double in size of the screen resolution and should have the @2x.png (or jpg) suffix. Example: `Background-Image@2x.png`